# How to add examples to API documentation in Go?

Tags: api, documentation, go

There are some nice [executable examples](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#example_Join) in the Go standard library. How can I add such an example to my own API documentation?

Comment: Have you tried sourcing saved links from [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org)? Or is this question more about how to actually embed them in your own docs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Output of `$ go help testfunc`:

> The 'go test' command expects to find test, benchmark, and example functions
>   in the "*_test.go" files corresponding to the package under test.
>
> A test function is one named TestXXX (where XXX is any alphanumeric string
>   not starting with a lower case letter) and should have the signature,

```
 func TestXXX(t *testing.T) { ... }
```

> A benchmark function is one named BenchmarkXXX and should have the signature,

```
 func BenchmarkXXX(b *testing.B) { ... }
```

> An example function is similar to a test function but, instead of using *testing.T
>   to report success or failure, prints output to os.Stdout and os.Stderr.
>   That output is compared against the function's "Output:" comment, which
>   must be the last comment in the function body (see example below). An
>   example with no such comment, or with no text after "Output:" is compiled
>   but not executed.
>
> Godoc displays the body of ExampleXXX to demonstrate the use
>   of the function, constant, or variable XXX.  An example of a method M with
>   receiver type T or *T is named ExampleT_M.  There may be multiple examples
>   for a given function, constant, or variable, distinguished by a trailing _xxx,
>   where xxx is a suffix not beginning with an upper case letter.
>
> Here is an example of an example:

```
func ExamplePrintln() {
        Println("The output of\nthis example.")
        // Output: The output of
        // this example.
}
```

> The entire test file is presented as the example when it contains a single
>   example function, at least one other function, type, variable, or constant
>   declaration, and no test or benchmark functions.
>
> See the documentation of the testing package for more information.